# cartodb: ssl version of the light_all basemap

Tags: carto, carto-js

Is there an ssl version for cartodb light_all basemap ?

I am currently using the following code via leaflet.js

    `L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        noWrap: true,
        detectRetina: true
    }).addTo(map);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the following urls:

```
https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

available subdomains are: `abcd`

you can use `subdomains` leaflet option http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-subdomains

Comment: great, thanks. I couldn't find it anywhere on the website/repo

Comment: It's well documented now at least - https://carto.com/location-data-services/basemaps/